# Android, onPrepareDialog to update parameter-ized string not updating.

Tags: android

This does not seem to be working. The alert dialogs are not even showing a title or message unless I set them in the onCreateDialog method.

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);

    switch(id) {
    case R.id.catalog_rename_dialog:
        ((AlertDialog) dialog).setTitle(getString(R.string.catalog_rename_prompt, catalogDb.getColumnById(selectedCatalogId, CatalogDbAdapter.KEY_NAME)));
        break;
    case R.id.catalog_delete_dialog:
        ((AlertDialog) dialog).setMessage(getString(R.string.delete_prompt, catalogDb.getColumnById(selectedCatalogId, CatalogDbAdapter.KEY_NAME)));
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a fix for onPrepareDialog not showing the message set with setMessage.  When initially creating the dialog (when it's still an AlertDialog.Builder), you have to set the message to an initial state (not null) or onPrepareDialog will NOT overwrite it with the intended value.  So when you're creating the dialog, do something like this to always have a non-null value in the message.  I struggled with this for days and found this solution by accident:

when initially creating the dialog (NOT in onPrepareDialog):

```
AlertDialog.Builder resultAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

if ( message == null ) {
    resultAlert.setMessage("");
} else {
    resultAlert.setMessage(message);
}
```

then in onPrepareDialog, you should be able to overwrite the value with whatever string you want using dialog.setMessage( yourMessage ).  This seems to be a defect in Google's code (I think they call that a bug.)

Comment: Yep, it's a bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6489. You must init the message with a non-null value in onCreateDialog in order for setMessage() to work in onPrepareDialog.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing create and prepare behaviour.

- [onCreateDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) is used to setup the controls present on a dialog. It is called once.
- [onPrepareDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog,%20android.os.Bundle%29) is used to customise the displayed values. It is called every time a dialog is shown